# multiple mysql databases using php

Tags: php, mysql

I know how to connect with two databases using the true parameter given as link identifier as fourth parameter.
But if there are more than two databases.What can i do for that?

Comment: i know that to connect to 2 databases.but how can i connect to 3 database.plz help

Comment: $con1=mysql_connect("$host","$user","$pass");
$con2=mysql_connect("$host","$user2","$pass",true);
$con3=mysql_connect("$host","$user3","$pass");
mysql_select_db($db_name,$con1);
mysql_select_db($db_name2,$con2);
mysql_select_db($db_name3,$con3);
What can i do for third one.Or simply leaving like that can connect to the specified connect.

Comment: ajreal,i am from mobile and newbie to this site its showing the code should have to intend with 4 spaces i do not know to do that.please read the code from comment.

Comment: then say how can i intend the 4 spaces or what does it mean

Answer (score 2):

You can make multiple calls to

```
mysql_connect()
```

```
$dbh1 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password); 
$dbh2 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password, true); 

mysql_select_db('database1', $dbh1);
mysql_select_db('database2', $dbh2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make multiple calls to `mysql_connect()`, but if the parameters are the same you need to pass true for the '`$new_link`' (fourth) parameter, otherwise the same connection is reused.

so then you have

```
$dbh1 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password); 
$dbh2 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password, true); 

mysql_select_db('database1', $dbh1);
mysql_select_db('database2', $dbh2);
```

Then to query database 1, do

```
mysql_query('select * from tablename', $dbh1);
```

and for database 2

```
mysql_query('select * from tablename', $dbh2);
```

Alternatively, if the mysql user has access to both databases and they are on the same host (i.e. both DBs are accessible from the same MySQL connection) you could:

- Keep one connection open and keep calling `mysql_select_db()` to swap between. I don't think this is a clean solution and you will easily get cases where you query the wrong db etc.
- Use queries where you specify the database name (e.g. `SELECT * FROM database2.tablename`), but this is again likely to be a pain to implement.

Comment: what to do if i have to connect to third database and third mysql connection

Comment: @todda.speot.is can you please give me the code for the third one.

Comment: All you need to change database from job to job.

mysql_select_db('db1');

// -- do some queries on 'db1' database

mysql_select_db('db2');

// -- do some queries on 'db2' database


mysql_select_db('db3');

// -- do some queries on 'db3' database

Answer (score 0):

> using the true parameter given as link identifier as fourth parameter

...only if both ( or all) the databases are running on the same mysql instance *and* use the same username *and* password to connect - if you've got reason to split stuff across separate databases, then usually there's reason to separate the authentication too.

And if authentication is not split (and even sometimes where it is split) you don't need 2 different handles to access data on the same instance:

```
 SELECT a.*, b.* 
 FROM db_1.a_table a
   INNER JOIN db_2.a_table b
   ON (a.id=b.id)
```